# Opencart 1.5.4 - not validate minimum order quantity for different option of same product

Tags: php, opencart

For my Opencart 1.5.4 project, we have set the minimum 12 quantity for product. If the user select the quantity less than 12 it will not allow user to buy it (Opencart validate this on cart page). But if user selects  the same product in the group of different option (small, medium, large) individual less than 12 then he can place the order.

**For e.g.**

> Product A (small)    6 Qty
>
> Product A (medium)    6 Qty
>
> Product A (large)    10 Qty
>
> **Total quantity is 22.**

But I want individual item quantity is `minimum 12` like below,

> Product A (small)    12 Qty (minimum 12)
>
> Product A (medium)    12 Qty  (minimum 12)
>
> Product A (large)    12 Qty  (minimum 12)

Opencart is not treated different options as different product in cart and user can easily buy individual product in less than 12 quantity.

Can any one suggest me why this happen and how to fix this issue? Any extension is available for that?

Comment: I am not sure but what if you define a custom rule for this validation?

Comment: @SougataBose Opencart is not provide custom rule facility by default.

Comment: @SougataBose check the answer I have found the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution of this issue, for that  I have to make changes in  the **cart and checkout controller**. By default Opencart is calculating the product quantity on the cart page by product id. I have customized the code and now it will check the individual quantity of each product in the cart.

> Cart controller ==> Cart.php  \catalog\controller\checkout\cart.php
>   make changes in line no 192 to 197

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

    $product_total = 0;
    $allCartProductId[] = $product['product_id'];
    foreach ($products as $product_2) {
        if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
            $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
        }
    }

    if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
        $this->data['error_warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_minimum'), $product['name'], $product['minimum']) 
    }
}
```

> To

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

                $product_total = 0;
                $allCartProductId[] = $product['product_id'];

                        $product_total += $product['quantity'];

                if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
                    $this->data['error_warning'] .= sprintf($this->language->get('error_minimum'), $product['name'], $product['minimum'])."<br>";
                }
```

> Checkout controller ==> checkout.php 
>   \catalog\controller\checkout\checkout.php make changes in line no 15
>   to 20

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_total = 0;

        foreach ($products as $product_2) {
            if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
                $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
            }
        }
```

> To

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product_total = 0;         
    $product_total += $product['quantity'];
```